# Setting initial scroll in tables in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to set initial scroll in reactjs material-ui tables?

The table I am using has many columns, and would prefer if some of the columns come into view automatically upon loading without scrolling i.e. setting initial scroll.

Is this even possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution best suited for myself.

I took three references:

---

- one for the parent table
- one for the first column of the table
- one for the column till where I have to scroll

then within the `useLayoutEffect`, I use the `getClientBoundingRect` to get the coordinates of the two columns and finally use the `tableRef.current.scrollTo()` with the difference between the coordinates to scroll to the required position.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) and [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).
You can change the property using javascript